# Youtube ReferenceConflicts - Invalid next page token

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to paginate on "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/referenceConflicts" however I am receiving an invalid token from the first page as shown below:

```json
  "kind": "youtubePartner#referenceConflictList",
  "nextPageToken": "\u0001aֻr�\fj�1ϜT�Y\r0m��v�b�:�RUN%�$Ns�#�N�#�؜�\u001eҀr�/�R\u003ct�\\'Q��8�\u000b��go\u0005\u0010_\u0004�4F[f�$-��%",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 226
  },
```

Even if I try to send it as it is to retrieve the next page, I receive this exception

```
     Message[Invalid Value] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]
```

Comment: Can you share the url request you're making? - don't share the API KEY, just the code you're using.

Comment: Also, is this the full detail of the response? - I found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#BAD_REQUEST) that `invalid` refers to: `The request failed because it contained an invalid value. The value could be a parameter value, a header value, or a property value.` Are you sure the token is a valid one? - I've never seen a token with those characters...

Comment: This request only takes onBehalfOfContentOwner parameter and here it is the full URL: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/referenceConflicts/list?apix_params=%7B%22onBehalfOfContentOwner%22%3A%22jZsWFEkXc1PMySLKhkfcZw%22%7D @MauricioAriasOlave

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave you're right i have read the documentation and it didn't help me at all, actually I am using most of youtube APIs for a years ago, this is the first time to face this issue.

Most of their APIs return valid nextpagetoken not encrypted like this

Comment: Consider post a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&;template=874803&pli=1&template=874803) - this *might* be a bug with the API or some undocumented behaviour. Best of luck.